# Using the results of a non-metric multidimensional scaling to derive a measure of deviance

Tags: measurement, multidimensional-scaling, deviance

I'm working with a dataset containing the taxonomic compositions of floras all over the world and performed a non-metric multidimensional scaling (NMDS) based on the relative proportions of plant families within each flora.

**My question:** Is it mathematically correct to use the (Euclidean) distance to the coordinate origin in order to quantify the deviance of a flora from a hypothetical average composition?

Comment: There would seem to be no issue of "mathematical" correctness: Euclidean distance is a *bona fide* distance. Aren't you rather concerned about whether using it is *appropriate* for your analysis? If so, this seems to be a question that is more about your objectives and the subject matter than it is about statistics. For it to be answerable I believe you would need to tell us more about your objectives and the data you have.

Comment: I try to give a short summary.

Comment: The dataset contains about 450 spatial units, for each of which I have gathered complete species inventories. They largely differ in size, species number and geographic location. Based on a taxonomic classification I could assign to each species the family it belongs to. My aim is to find the link between compositional bias in floras and other variables such as area, distance to the mainland, etc. Therefore I need a way to measure the bias in the first place...